# Ant-design cloned in github could'n run

Tags: antd

I clone ant-design in github and want to run it according to the official guide.but it could't work.
the error :

```
  throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK();
  ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
    at maybeCallback (fs.js:140:9)
    at Object.fs.writeFile (fs.js:1258:14)
    at module.exports (/Users/sufang/ant-design/node_modules/_bisheng-plugin-antd@0.16.3@bisheng-plugin-antd/lib/process-demo.js:142:8)
    at module.exports (/Users/sufang/ant-design/node_modules/_bisheng-plugin-antd@0.16.3@bisheng-plugin-antd/lib/node.js:14:12)
    at /Users/sufang/ant-design/node_modules/_bisheng@0.28.3@bisheng/lib/utils/source-data.js:210:30
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Object.exports.process (/Users/sufang/ant-design/node_modules/_bisheng@0.28.3@bisheng/lib/utils/source-data.js:209:32)
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/sufang/ant-design/node_modules/_bisheng@0.28.3@bisheng/lib/loaders/common/worker.js:13:35)
    at process.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:807:12)
```

can anyone know how to resolve this problem？ thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fixed in https://github.com/ant-design/bisheng-plugin-antd/commit/2f6c5db91ebe352017ae989cdd03cc46845e0573 by now. Try reintall node_modules and start again.